# Question on Inline editing for 1 permission set on a Salesforce custom object.is this only at the Org level?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

i really only need Inline editing for `1 permission set on a custom object` i'm working on,is this only at the Org level?,

so if `it's enabled everyone will see it` and on all objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,this is an org configuration. However, there are few more considerations like profile edit permissions, etc.

Check the following article for more details.
https://salesforcethinkers.home.blog/2019/09/10/inline-editing-in-salesforce-mass-edit-records/